# React.js: How to do sorting correctly based on API call?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting

I'm learning **React.js** and encountered this for the first time.
I am fetching **API data** and want to be able to **sort** the **data** based on the attributes on the cards themselves.
 So, I use **Switch** to handle multiple sorting. When I click for the first time,  it seems to work, but when I click again to another **button**, **app** stops responding and there is no **error** to figure out what's the problem. It just stops working. 
I tried with **useMemo**  as well, but no difference. 
 Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code structure:

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function useCountries(search: string, activeFilter: any) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([])
  const [savedCountries, setSavedCountries] = useState<any[]>([])
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setData(result)
        setSavedCountries(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = [...savedCountries].filter((item: any) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )
    setData(result)
  }, [search, savedCountries])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const sortCountry = (countries: any) => {
      const filter = activeFilter.toLowerCase()
      switch (filter) {
        case 'flag':
          const sortByFlag = [...countries].sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            a.flag.localeCompare(b.flag)
          )
          setData(sortByFlag)
          break
        case 'region':
          const sortByRegion = [...countries].sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            a.region.localeCompare(b.region)
          )
          setData(sortByRegion)
          break
        case 'language':
          const sortByLanguages = [...countries].sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            a.languages[0].name.localeCompare(b.languages[0].name)
          )
          setData(sortByLanguages)
          break
        case 'population':
          const sortPopulation = [...countries].sort(
            (a: any, b: any) => a.population - b.population
          )
          setData(sortPopulation)
          break
        case 'name':
          const sortByName = [...countries].sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
          )
          setData(sortByName)
          break
      }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    sortCountry(data)
  }, [activeFilter, data, sortCountry])

  return [data]
}
```

component for onClick

```
import React from 'react'

/* import { HeaderProps } from '../../types'
 */
import './Header.scss'

export default function Header({ setActiveFilter }: any) {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <ul className="HeadTableRow">
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => setActiveFilter('flag')}>Flag</button>
        </li>{' '}
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => setActiveFilter('name')}>Name</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => setActiveFilter('language')}>Language</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => setActiveFilter('population')}>
            Population
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => setActiveFilter('region')}>Region</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: put code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging better

Comment: Your problem is that when the Flag `Name` `Language`  `Population‍‍` is clicked, it does not sort
Did I get it right?

Comment: Hi @A.R.SEIF actually it works from the first click, but if I click again to another sort button, app will stop working, I'll have to refresh to make it work again. Check the link

Comment: Hi @Greg. i am check the code .I made changes to it [codesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shtern-g543c?file=/src/Hooks/useCountries.tsx).
But still, by clicking on the titles a few times, it is arranged only once, because the amount of the activeFilter does not change.follow this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#tip-pass-information-between-hooks)

Comment: Hi @A.R.SEIF thanks for help. Actually it works now, but there is still smth wrong. There is a warning in 'useEffect'  array, that says 'React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies : data and sortCountry'; Either include them or remove the dependency array' .  It is a eslint warning that doesn't allow to use Github actions. 
How can I solve it?
Thank you beforehand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224546/discussion-between-a-r-seif-and-greg).